# Any alternate spatial correlation/regression method than Moren' I and GWR

Tags: r, spatial, autocorrelation

I have economic and health indicators for a city. I want to find spatial correlation between say mental health scores of the people with their average income. If I use Moran's I, then I can only see one indicator's spatial correlation i.e. the Mental health scores or, the average income scores are not random, there is clustered values. But, I want to find the correlation between mental health and average income or, any two/three variables with geographical location being a factor.

Say for example, my research question is - people in high income regions face more mental health problems than people in low income regions. I know I can just do Pearson's correlation to find a correlation between mental health and average income but, it has no location/ spatial component to the analysis. Is there any theoritical/practical way how I can find spatial correlation between variables? I am looking at GWR or, Geographically Weighted Regressions. Any thoughts? By the way, I am using R.

Comment: Can you give some more details of your problem? Sample size? ... Maybe better look into a regression model with spatially correlated errors ...

Answer (score 1):

I àm using something called "synthetic population" by which I had calculated health related 3 parameters (physical health score, mental health score, subjective wellbeing) and economic indicators (rent, average income, ...etc 7 indicators ). I am trying to find correlation between health indicators and economic indicators. If I use Pearson's correlation, there is relationship but it does not take into account the geographic locations. I want the use of geographic locations or spatial data (which I have calculated by local authority units/different segments of the city)...

I can use GWR method to find the relationship between them ...so, any similar experience or alternative suggestions would be helpful !

Kind regards
Imran

Answer (score 0):

Spatial autocorrelation is helpful as exploratory spatial data analysis. After finding it, it would be nice to investigate what is causing spatial autocorrelation and how it is related to the available variables.

It would be nice and helpful to model your response variable using the possible explanatory variables by means of different modelling techniques, such as generalized linear mixed models, as you seem to have different sorts of variables. After getting the models, you may choose to see if the spatial autocorrelation is still there, maybe checking if the residuals still show spatial autocorrelation.

Some descriptions and explanations of the process and models could be seen in 'Bivand, Roger S., Edzer J. Pebesma, Virgilio Gómez-Rubio, and Edzer Jan Pebesma. Applied spatial data analysis with R. Vol. 747248717. New York: Springer, 2008.'

This is a very interesting topic, closely related to my research methods. Hope this helps, and I would look forward to seeing how you figure this out.

Comment: This answer could use more supporting information, documentation, or other means of answering the question. As it stands, this answer is incredibly vague and doesn't really say much.

Comment: Im not sure how I have harassed you. Thank you at least for editing your answer to include some references.